# Como fazer border CSS herdar cor?

Tags: html, css

Galera montei um container simples usando CSS. Para eu fazer a `DIV` que recebe o texto ficar com background azul eu chão uma classe que criei para colocar background onde eu a chamar. Porém preciso colocar a borda azul na `DIV` que recebe o conteúdo. Como faço para a borda herdar a cor da classe 
`bg-blue-3`? Se possível queria fazer isso no HTML, pois vou criar vários containers com cores diferentes.

```css
.bg-blue-3 {
    background-color: #42A5F5 !important;
}

.step-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
.step-container-head {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
.step-container-body {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="step-container container-width">
    <div class="step-container-head bg-blue-3">
        TEXTO
    </div>
    <div class="step-container-body">
        conteudo
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não é possivel via CSS importar a côr de um parente próxmio. Com pre-compiladores de CSS como o Stylus é possivel criar variáveis e assim fazer um pouco DRY e colocar somente a côr em 1 sítio e a variável propagar isso.

Mas em CSS nativo não dá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pré-processando seu CSS

Herdar simplesmente com css não seria possível, pois apesar de ser a mesma cor, está aplicada em propriedades diferentes. Uma solução seria utilizar um pré-processador de css, como o less ou o sass. Através dele você poderia criar mixins (variáveis) dentro do seu css, então você poderia atribuir o valor de uma cor a variável, e colocá-la na border e no background-color. Toda vez que você mudasse o valor dessa variável, mudaria em todos os lugares em que ela está sendo referenciada. Veja os tutoriais de como instalar o less e como usar mixin:

Como instalar: http://paradadigital.com/2013/11/01/instalar-compilador-de-less-no-nodejs.html

Criar mixin e outros recursos: http://blog.caelum.com.br/css-facil-flexivel-e-dinamico-com-less/

Ps: Se você quiser que a cor de ambas mude em tempo de execução (após a página ter sido carregada), será possível apenas com javascript.

Comment: ok vou criar uma class chamada boder e sempre chamo  ela no html assim atribui a borda. exemplo: <div class="step-container-body boder">